# SqlKata query takes each individual element of the collection as an additional parameter

Tags: c#, postgresql, sqlkata

I'm trying to pass **multiple** ids to postgres function.

```
Test(new[] { 1, 2 });

static void Test(IEnumerable<int> ids)
{
    var db = new QueryFactory(new SqlConnection(""), new SqlServerCompiler());

    var query = db.Query("").FromRaw($"Test.Test(?)", ids);

    var compiler = new SqlServerCompiler();
    SqlResult result = compiler.Compile(query);
    string sql = result.Sql; // SELECT * FROM Test.Test(@p0,@p1)
}
```

Instead of 1 parameter (`IEnumerable<int>`) query creates 2 (`@p0,@p1`).

Why is this happening and how to fix it?

Comment: try passing `new[] { new [] {1, 2 } }`

Comment: what are u expecting as result ?

Comment: there is no documentation arround functions calling on SQLKata but I think that the way is preparing the value as raw "ARRAY[1, 2, 3, NULL, 5]"
var rawParam = $"ARRAY[{ string.Join(",",new[] { 1, 2 }) }]"

Comment: @rolivares 1 parameter, not 2. amd's answer was helpfull.